# How to I turn transaction fees into basis points

Tags: percentages

How do I turn a transaction fee into basis points for merchant services? Let's say i have

1000 transactions

$25.00 avg ticket

150 bps per transaction +

$0.25 transaction fee

How do I find the total paid in BPS?

Comment: 1 basis point = 0.01%.

Comment: Thank you, but that isn't what I was asking. I am asking how to turn the $0.25 into basis points to add to the 150 bps for a total bps paid.

Comment: $0.25/25.00=.01=100$ BPS.  Therefore, the total equivalent BPS is $150+100=250$.

Comment: thank you so much for the prompt response